# Why does Google Closure think Exception is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I tried running [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) on my code with `-W VERBOSE`

This simple statement

```
throw new Exception ("hello");
```

yields an error

```
variable Exception is undeclared
```

I thought `Exception` was standard. Is Closure wrong, or should I be declaring Exception somehow before throwing it? (My code runs fine in Firefox.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be throwing [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)'s instead of `Exception`'s:

```
throw new Error('hello');
```

(`throw new Exception()` doesn't work in my Firefox, not sure why it works for you)